# Volume of revolution Finding the volume

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

> Find the volume of revolution of $y=7-x$ and $xy=6$ about the x-axis

$xy=6\Rightarrow y=\frac{6}{x}$

$7-x=\frac{6}{x}\Rightarrow 7x-x^2-6=0$ so $x_1=1$ and $x_2=6$

$y=7-x$ cut the y-axis at $x=0$ and x-axis at $x=7$

So I have $\pi\int_{0}^{7}(7-x)^2-(\frac{6}{x})^2dx$?

Comment: Should be $\pi\int_{1}^{6}(7-x)^2-(\frac{6}{x})^2dx$ not $\pi\int_{0}^{7}(7-x)^2-(\frac{6}{x})^2dx$

Comment: @KennyGuy why from 1 to 6 $y=\frac{6}{x}$ has a value at $X=\frac{1}{2}$ for example, so it should be take into account?

Comment: Nope, you take to account values where the two functions intersect and use those two numbers for definite integration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have found out that the quadratic equation $7x-x^2-6=0$ has solutions $x=1$ and $x=6$

These values 1 and 6 are where the two functions meet so therefore volume of revolution is $\pi\int_{1}^{6}(7-x)^2-(\frac{6}{x})^2dx$

$\pi\int_{1}^{6}49-14x+x^2-36x^{-2} dx$

$\pi \left[\frac{1}{3} x^3-7x^2+49x+36x^{-1}\right]^6_1$

$\pi[72-252+294+6]-\pi[\frac{1}{3}-7+49+36]$

$\pi [(120)-(\frac{17}{3})]$

$\frac{343\pi}{3}units^2$